# How to disable refactoring in vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode has added a 'Refactor...' editor context menu option from version 1.70 onwards. This is unnecessary when developing an extension that does not support refactoring. The option simply gives the error 'No refactorings available'.

Is there a way to disable this context menu option? Normally options only show up when we register their providers like DefinitionProvider for 'Go to Definition', but this one seems to popup without any registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside settings, *Editor* > *Snippets* > *Code Actions:* **Enabled**

[image]

Can toggle this **off** to disable the menu option.